# Edit "Email Name" for Portal Users

Tags: email, apex-email-service

Does anyone know where is "Email Name" field value stored in salesfroce. This field appears under My Setting -> Email -> My Email Settings (refer image attached). We want to update this field with Account Name of the portal user's contact record.

[image]

Thank you for any help!

Best Regards

Yash Mehta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That field is stored in User.SenderName:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Email, SenderName, SenderEmail FROM User
```